# SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects error on extended properties of the table indexes

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-migration

I have a SSIS task to migrate tables from one DB to another.

Source DB version: `SQL Server 12.0.4422.0`
Destination DB version: `SQL Server 14.0.3281.6`

SSIS target version: `SQL Server 2016`

The configuration looks like this: (I want to transfer extended properties as well)

[image]

Everything works fine when `IncludeExtendedProperties` option is set to `False`. But when I set it to `True` I am getting the following error:

```
Object is invalid. Extended properties are not permitted on 'dbo.TABLE_NAME.INDEX_KEY_NAME', or the object does not exist.
```

**UPDATE:**

So, after thorough investigation, I found out that all extended properties are transferred just fine. The issue only arises when there exists an extended property on the index of any column. Still unable to figure out that part...

Comment: You could fire up an extended event and capture the DDL that comes across the wire to see what commands are being issued in an attempt to identify what is awry. I have a post about using [Extended Events to capture bad queries](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2015/08/tracking-bad-queries-aka-finally.html) that might be a useful starting point. That said, my guess is that if extended properties don't work on the transfer (and it's not permission related), it's a defect with the Task and likely won't be fixable by end users.

Comment: @billinkc will take a look, thanks. The task itself seems fine because I am successfully using it for other DBs. The issue seems to be with either source SQL Server Version or some DB configuration (i.e. user)

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out the cause and it might be helpful for others, so posting this as an answer.

In MSSQL if you don't define constraints(i.e Primary Keys) with names, it uses a generated names of type `PK_COLUMNNAME_RANDOMNUMBER`.

Now in SSIS, if you try to transfer the objects with generated constraint names to the new destination, the query that does it also creates a new generated names in the destination. So after the transfer the constraint names between the source and destination DBs are different.

In addition, the query that tries to transfer the **Extended Properties** from source to destination, is trying to use the same names for both.

So, here are possible workarounds that I tested to make this work:

- All your constraints are using the predefined names.

or

- you simply don't have extended properties on the constraints at all.

I'm not sure if there exists any other solution or if it was accounted in any later versions of SSIS.